# Stretch Relative Positioned DIV with content

Tags: html, css

I have the following CSS which enables me to center my page

```
#mainholder {
    position:relative;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width:1000px;
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    min-height:1100px;
    z-index:1;
    clear:both;
}
```

Inside the #mainholder div, I have another DIV which contains my data which will increase or decrease in height depemding on the content. The CSS is below

```
#maincontentdiv {
    position:absolute;
    width:955px;
    min-height:795px;       
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:thin;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    left:10px;
    top: 135px;     

}
```

The problem I am having is that while #maincontentdiv stretches as expected the #mainholder does not stretch with the contents of #maincontentdiv. I would like to know how to solve this issue or what other options are out there.

All help will be greatly appreciated
Thanks

**EDIT**

As requested, here is the HTML code

```
<div id="mainholder">
  <div id="topnavbar">
    <div id="navlinks">

    </div>

  </div>
  <div id="messagediv">

  </div>
  <div id="maincontentdiv">
    <table width="100%" border="0">
      <tr bgcolor="#507CD1">
        <td width="19%">Grant ID</td>
        <td width="61%">Grant Description</td>
        <td width="20%">Manage</td>
      </tr>
      <?php 
      $select = " SELECT QUERY THAT WILL CHANGE THE LENGTH OF THE DIV DEPENDING ON RESULTS

";
     $query = sqlsrv_query($conn,$select,array(),array("Scrollable"=>SQLSRV_CURSOR_STATIC))or die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors()));
     while($row=sqlsrv_fetch_array($query))
     {
        //variables
       ?>
      <tr>
        <td><?php echo $variable ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $variable ?></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <?php }?>
    </table>
  </div>
  <br style="clear:both"/>
</div>
```

Comment: please  show the relevant html

Comment: Try by adding "height:auto" to the outer div.

Comment: @NullPointer added as requested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `position:absolute` for your inner div. So its position will not affect the parent div.

```
#maincontentdiv {
    position:absolute;
    width:955px;
    min-height:795px;       
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:thin;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    left:10px;
    top: 135px;     

}
```

change this  to

```
#maincontentdiv {
    position:relative;
    width:955px;
    min-height:795px;       
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:thin;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    margin-left:10px;
    margin-top: 135px;     
}
```

Let me know if you still have the problem.

Comment: It works upto some point. The outer div stretches but not completely. I margn-left:10px and margin-top:135px seem to hide my maincontentdiv and distort my page. Changing them to left and top produces the effect described first: The outer div does not stretch fully

Comment: add margin-bottom or only bottom  for inner div. Then it will maintain the lower gap always.

Comment: Thank you sir. margin-bottom did the trick. I added top:110px; and margin-bottom:110px; and it worked out. Works even in IE